# Combine fadeIn effect with .css() jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, display

I'm working on the menu of my website, that you can open by clicking the hamburger menu button (`.menu-button`). When clicked, it opens the div `#menu` (this div covers the whole viewport) by running the following script:

```
<script>
    $('.menu-button').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#menu').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#menu').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, I'd like to make the `#menu` div appear with a fadeIn effect. So having this code, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you need and simplify the logic by using [`fadeToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle) instead:

```js
$('.menu-button').on('click', function() {
  $('#menu').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-button">Toggle menu...</button>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On click event you could toggle a class on the menu element which triggers a `CSS` transition

```
<script>
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    $('.menu-button').on('click', function() {
        menu.classList.toggle('visible');
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s 0s;
}

#menu.visible {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: is it better in term of optimisation to target an element with native `getElementById` than a jquery css query selector?

Comment: every call to a jQuery method which return a node collection is actually a wrapper to a native method, so in general every call to jQuery will be slower than calling the native method. This is also true for `click()/on()` vs. `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) and the callback to `display:hide` after the animation

```js
    $('.menu-button').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#menu').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
          $('#menu').animate({'opacity':'1'},400)
        } else {
            
          $('#menu').animate({'opacity':'0'},400,function(){
            $('#menu').css('display', 'none');
          })
        }
    });
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

#menu {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu-button'>
</div>
<div id='menu' style='display:none'>
  dzq
</div>
```